# Twitter bootstrap img-circle when try to add border in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The class img-circle creates a rounded image as you probably guessed. Now, when you try to add border to that class it behaves weird: it makes the image square with cut-off edges. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome btw.

Please see the attached files to see the difference and also the code!

[image: Safari]  [image: Chrome and Firefox]

```
div#face-wrapper .face {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 border: 15px solid #e8e6e6;
}
.img-circle {
-webkit-border-radius: 500px;
-moz-border-radius: 500px;
border-radius: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the border is always behind the image, so once you are using css3 for border-radius, why don't you use box-shadow for borders? ex.:

[**DEMO**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/po5ftvcb)

`.box-shadow{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 15px #e8e6e6; /* Firefox */

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 15px #e8e6e6; /* Safari, Chrome */

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 15px #e8e6e6; /* CSS3 */
}`

Comment: You are right! I used box shadow but instead of putting the code in the face-wrapper I put it into .img-circle(I don't know why I did that!). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit [simpler](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/yqpg5/) method, using a 'shrink-wrap' `span`.

### HTML

```
<span id="face-wrapper">
  <img class="img-circle face" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdlzsBNiqrnes9kVJ3zTReXHfgca2qkDD1kgvCR82OxzYsPaTz" width="200"/>
</span>
```

### CSS

```
#face-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:#e8e6e6; 
}

.face {
  position: relative;
  border: 20px solid #e8e6e6;
}
```

And the full [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/yqpg5/).